# The html_table function in rvest is skipping a row

Tags: r, html-table

I have found a particular table in which I need to use webscraping. The thing is that the first row of actual data that I need is being read, but is not being considered when converted to table.

I read the webpage with read_html(), and using SelectorGadget and the source code of the page, recognised the css class. I tried different css or xpaths.

When the first row (the second row of the actual table, as the fist one is only an id) is read, the html_table() does not include that row.

As you can see in the webpage's source code, there are a couple of extra rows without data, which are read as NA's. No problem there.

```r
url <- "https://www.spensiones.cl/apps/carteras/genera_xsl.php?fecpro=201801&listado=25"

tmp0 <- read_html(url)

# The css specification is the closest that I found reads the first row
tmp <- html_nodes(tmp0,".table, .table tr, td")

# check the node which has to be converted to table later
tmp[[1]]
```

As you can see, the `r tmp[[1]]` shows the rows 4 through 12 correspond to the first row of the actual table that I need. When I convert it to table, that data is not considered

```r
head(html_table(tmp[[1]], fill = TRUE),4)
```

The only thing I can think of, is that the format of the rows of the nodeset is different when comparing the first row with the ones that follow:

```r
{html_node}
<table class="table">
 [1] <tr>\n<th align="center">NEMOTECNICO</th>\n<th align="center">INSTITUCION</th>\n< ...
 [2] <tr></tr>\n
 [3] <tr><td align="left" colspan="9"><b>EMPRESAS EXTRANJERAS</b></td></tr>\n
 [4] <td align="left">LU0584671464</td>
 [5] <td align="left">ADECOAGRO SA</td>
 [6] <td align="right">16,37</td>
 [7] <td align="right">13,72</td>
 [8] <td align="right">20,36</td>
 [9] <td align="right">2,60</td>
[10] <td align="right">1,18</td>
[11] <td align="right">54,23</td>
[12] <td align="right">0,02</td>
[13] <tr>\n<td align="left">US0126531013</td>\n<td align="left">ALBEMARLE CORP</td>\n< ...
[14] <tr>\n<td align="left">USP0156PAB50</td>\n<td align="left">ALFA SAB DE CV</td>\n< ...
...
```

The thing is, the source code of the webpage is not the same, as the original has the `r <tr></tr>` in that first row.

Thanks for the help!